# Print a list of space-separated elements

Tags: python, pretty-print

I have a list `L` of elements, say natural numbers.  I want to print them in one line with a **single space** as a separator.  But I **don't want** a space after the last element of the list (or before the first).

In Python 2, this can easily be done with the following code.  The implementation of the `print` statement (mysteriously, I must confess) avoids to print an extra space before the newline.

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for x in L:
    print x,
print
```

However, in Python 3 it seems that the (supposedly) equivalent code using the `print` function produces a space after the last number:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for x in L:
    print(x, end=" ")
print()
```

Of course there are easy answers to my question.  I know I can use string concatenation:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(" ".join(str(x) for x in L))
```

This is a quite good  solution, but compared to the Python 2 code I find it counter-intuitive and definitely slower.  Also, I know I can choose whether to print a space or not myself, like:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i, x in enumerate(L):
    print(" " if i>0 else "", x, sep="", end="")
print()
```

but again this is worse than what I had in Python 2.

So, my question is, am I missing something in Python 3?  Is the behavior I'm looking for supported by the `print` function?

Comment: I think the `join` solution is bad because: (1) it explicitly uses `str`, which I find ugly and counter-intuitive, and most importantly (2) it first constructs a string and then prints it, which may be a bad idea if the list is long.

Comment: I'm not sure why @Braiam edited the title and removed "in Python 3".  The original question, many years ago, was about a difference in practice between Python 2 and Python 3.  Anyway...

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can apply the list as separate arguments:

```
print(*L)
```

and let `print()` take care of converting each element to a string. You can, as always, control the separator by setting the `sep` keyword argument:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print(*L)
1 2 3 4 5
>>> print(*L, sep=', ')
1, 2, 3, 4, 5
>>> print(*L, sep=' -> ')
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5
```

Unless you need the joined string for something else, this is the easiest method. Otherwise, use `str.join()`:

```
joined_string = ' '.join([str(v) for v in L])
print(joined_string)
# do other things with joined_string
```

Note that this requires manual conversion to strings for any non-string values in `L`!

Comment: This answers my question and is actually faster in Python 3 than the `for` loop.  I'm puzzled, however, because in Python 3 this takes 2.5 sec. to print `list(range(1000000))`, whereas the original Python 2 `for` loop takes 0.36 sec.  Did printing degrade so much in Python3?

Comment: @nickie: Did you include the `list()` call in your timings? It's not needed for any of the code you posted nor my answer. `print()` is also a function call now, which has more overhead than the `print` statement, and Python 3 also adds an encoding step (albeit in C code) from unicode to bytes.

Comment: No, I created the list beforehand in both versions.  I can post code of the benchmark, if you find this interesting.  In understand the overhead, but we're talking about almost an order of magnitude.

Comment: @nickie in my benchmark: `lst = range(100*1000) ; for i in lst: print i, ` took ~0.04s, while in python3 `lst = range(100*1000) ; print(*lst)` took ~0.08s

Comment: @m.wasowski: I think the OP was using a loop in Python 3 as well.

Comment: for loop in Python 3 doubles time (to ~0.15s) on my box

Comment: @m.wasowski: `range` in Python 2 returns a list whereas in Python 3 a generator object.  Anyway, the question was not primarily about performance and I feel reluctant to clutter it with benchmarking code.  If you and/or Martijn think that continuing this discussion is interesting, I can post a new question.  Thank you both, again.

Comment: I can reproduce a large increase in time in Python 3 for the `for i in L: print(i, end=' ')` loop, yes; about 4.5 times as much time over 10 repeats with `timeit` and `stdout` set to `/dev/null`. The difference lies in the function call (stack push and pop) and the more complex I/O structure (encoding unicode to bytes).

Comment: To a terminal the performance should be a non-issue, but if the target is a file, someone might be tempted to do something like `print(*L, sep='\n', file=f)` for a very large list. The issue here -- possibly (the list would have to be *huge*) -- is that the interpreter will create 2 tuples from list `L` that exist for the duration of the call.

Comment: We can also use join as in My answer.

Comment: @DeepakYadav: sure, but at the cost of creating a single larger string you then discard again, plus string objects for each and every value in the input list that isn't a string already. `print(..)` doesn't have to do most of that work, it just sends the data to the `stdout` buffer, which then can do any processing at the C level, and never has to create a new Python object in that process. That makes it all the more efficient.

Comment: Note that joining a generator expression should be faster than joining a list; that is `' '.join(str(v) for v in range(100*1000))` is faster than `' '.join([str(v) for v in range(100*1000)])`

Comment: @Bex It is **not** faster because string joining needs to know the total length up front and so makes two passes. To be able to do that a generator expression is consumed into a list first and so is **slower**. If you actually timed your two expressions you’ll find that your assertion doesn’t hold.

Comment: @Ben: see [Raymond Hettinger’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024) for timing runs.

Comment: what is * called in this reference? and what is this printing suing * operator called? Could someone point me out to the documentation? Thank you

Comment: @NithinGowda: That's part of the [call expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#calls), and I call it *argument expansion*. It's not an operator.

Answer (score 10):

Although the accepted answer is absolutely clear, I just wanted to check efficiency in terms of time.

The best way is to print joined string of numbers converted to strings.

```
print(" ".join(list(map(str,l))))
```

Note that I used **map** instead of **loop**.
I wrote a little code of all 4 different ways to compare time:

```
import time as t

a, b = 10, 210000
l = list(range(a, b))
tic = t.time()
for i in l:
    print(i, end=" ")

print()
tac = t.time()
t1 = (tac - tic) * 1000
print(*l)
toe = t.time()
t2 = (toe - tac) * 1000
print(" ".join([str(i) for i in l]))
joe = t.time()
t3 = (joe - toe) * 1000
print(" ".join(list(map(str, l))))
toy = t.time()
t4 = (toy - joe) * 1000
print("Time",t1,t2,t3,t4)
```

Result:

> Time 74344.76  71790.83  196.99  153.99

The output was quite surprising to me. Huge difference of time in cases of 'loop method' and 'joined-string method'.

Conclusion: Do not use loops for printing list if size is too large( in order of 10**5 or more).

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
for i in list[0:-1]:
    print(i, end=', ')
print(list[-1])
```

do for loops really take that much longer to run?

was trying to make something that printed all str values in a list separated by commas, inserting "and" before the last entry and came up with this:

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
for i in spam[0:-1]:
    print(i, end=', ')
print('and ' + spam[-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Joining elements in a list space separated:

```
word = ["test", "crust", "must", "fest"]
word.reverse()
joined_string = ""
for w in word:
   joined_string = w + joined_string + " "
print(joined_string.rstrim())
```