# Python Print parameter end

Tags: python

How to remove the last "add -->" from the output when using end, i am not using sep here, bcoz sep will not have any effect here , as the print statement prints just 1 item at a time here and ends with incr of i

```
def fibonaci_num(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fibonaci_num(n-1) + fibonaci_num(n-2)

N = 10

for i in range(N):
    print(fibonaci_num(i), end=' add -> ')
```

my output

```
0 add -> 1 add -> 1 add -> 2 add -> 3 add -> 5 add -> 8 add -> 13 add -> 21 add -> 34 add ->
```

Comment: You can't. The solution is to not use `end`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print a list of space-separated elements in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556449/print-a-list-of-space-separated-elements-in-python-3)

Comment: there should be some way

Comment: @Aran-Fey - nope , not matching to my case

Comment: Yep. Definitely matching your case. If you want to have an actual discussion about the topic, please start by explaining _why_ it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: `def fibonaci_num(n):    if n <= 1:        return n    else:        return fibonaci_num(n-1) + fibonaci_num(n-2)N = 10num = [fibonaci_num(i) for i in range(N)]print(*num, sep=' add -> ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inevitable pythonic one-liner:

```
print(*map(fibonaci_num, range(N)), sep=' add -> ')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use an if statement to check if its the last number:

```
def fibonaci_num(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    else:
        return fibonaci_num(n-1) + fibonaci_num(n-2)

N = 10

for i in range(N):
    print(fibonaci_num(i), end='')
    if i != N-1:
        print(' add -> ', end='')
```

Comment: Using Sep is better in every way, but if you aren't allowed to use that for some reason (maybe a class?) Then this works fine

Comment: @GrantWilliams: Is `sep` better in every way, or might it be less scalable?  Wouldn't the call using `*map()` expand the whole list into memory, whereas the `if` method would not?

Comment: @JeffLearman, hard to say as far as performance goes. I was mostly talking about ease of use/readability. It would be interesting to test it though. I would guess the best performance would come from using a list comprehension with sep, but im also too lazy to test it

Comment: Using a quick test with a generator, *args caused the whole list to be created, so in some cases it's not the best solution.  But not in the case of printing, so `sep` is definitely better here.

Answer (score 0):

Here I've simplified answer using ternary operator. May it will be helpful and better.

```
def fib(n):    
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        endstatement = '-' if (b < n) else ''
        print(a, end=endstatement)
        a, b = b, a+b
    print()


# Now call the function:
fib(1000)
```

> **Result**: 
>   `0-1-1-2-3-5-8-13-21-34-55-89-144-233-377-610-987`