# Removing whitespace from the end in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting extra whitespace after the end of output because I've used `end=' '`. How can I fix this?

```
for i in range(0,6):
    for g,h in q[i].items():
        print(h/len(q1[i]), end=" ") //here
    print()
```

[image]

Comment: Iterate one less and make a separate print statement for the last

Comment: Remove space from end. Try: `end=''`

Comment: Try `str.strip()`. It removes trailing whitespace.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani But won't that remove the spaces from the other outputs as well? I just don't want the whitespace in the end

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does the comma between the g and the h mean?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556449/print-a-list-of-space-separated-elements-in-python-3 may be helpful here.

Comment: @Kettle3D The comma is separating the dictionary's tuple pair, i.e. key,value

Comment: Oh, I get it. So it's like a tuple without braces. Sorry, I'm used to C#, where *everything* is surrounded in brackets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about having just one print statement per line? You can use `join` to put spaces between the values.

```py
for i in range(6):
    print(' '.join(str(h/len(q1[i])) for h in q[i].values()))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(0,6):
    print(*[h/len(q1[i]) for g,h in q[i].items()])
    print()
```

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22556506/5732397), we can simply unpack the list to print everything without the inner `for` loop.

Example:

```
>>> print(*[1,2,3])
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use str.join() to put spaces in between your items:

```py
for i in range(0,6):
    items = [str(h/len(q1[i])) for g,h in q[i].items()]
    print(" ".join(items))
```