# How do I delete the last space in the final output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = input().split()

for i in a:
    c = int(i)
    if c > 0:        
        b = c - 4
        d = b % 10
        if d != 0:
            print(i, "",  end='')
    else:
        e = c + 4
        f = e % 10
        if f != 0:
            print(i, "", end='')
```

This the whole code

The expected final output should be integers with space in between but no space at the end

By adding `""` I got spaces in between the elements.

So, how do I delete the space after the final, last element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print a list of space-separated elements in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556449/print-a-list-of-space-separated-elements-in-python-3)

Comment: FWIW, `e` and `f` are redundant for `b` and `d`. You could simplify by using a conditional expression like this: `b = c-4 if c>0 else c+4`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you store all you values to print in a list (so instead of print you append them to a list) and the at the end

```
print(*list)
```

Which will print each of the elements with a space in between.

Answer (score 1):

You can append your results to a list and then print the list.

```py
results = []
for i in a:
    c = int(i) 
    if c > 0:           
        b = c - 4    
        d = b % 10     
        if d != 0:        
            results.append(i)
    else:   
        e = c + 4
        f = e % 10
        if f != 0:
            results.append(i)

print(*results)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you do not want to create a list, you can count the elements, and use an if else statement to determine if it's the last element or not.

```
a = input().split()

for counter, i in enumerate(a):
    c = int(i)
    if c > 0:        
        b = c - 4
        d = b % 10
        if d != 0:
            if counter < len(a) - 1:
                print(i, "",  end='')
            else:
                print(i, end='')
    else:
        e = c + 4
        f = e % 10
        if f != 0:
            if counter < len(a) - 1:
                print(i, "", end='')
            else:
                print(i, end='')
```

Comment: It's simpler to use a conditional expression: `print(i, end=' ' if counter < len(a)-1 else '')`