# get arguments in variable with python

Tags: python, arguments, parameter-passing

I want to get all the arguments used in my python script in a variable

```
    print("\nArguments passed:", end = " ")
    n = len(sys.argv)
    for i in range(1, n):
        command = sys.argv[i]
        print(command)
```

how I can retrieve them in one row like :

```
print(command, end= " ")
```

```
arg1 arg2 arg3 arg3
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `print(*sys.argv, sep=' ')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Print a list of space-separated elements in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22556449/print-a-list-of-space-separated-elements-in-python-3)

Comment: I want get it in variable 'command'

Comment: `command = sys.argv[1:]` ??

Comment: thank you  mkrieger1 it work

Answer (score 0):

I would go with:

```python
import sys

args = ' '.join(sys.argv)

print(args)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
print("\nArguments passed:", end = " ")
    n = len(sys.argv)
    for i in range(1, n):
        command = sys.argv[1:]
    


print(command)
```

Comment: You don't need a loop for that.